# Using loop to display all the patients under single doctor

Tags: php, mysql, loops

This is my first time here and I want your kind advice. I'm preparing a system in php where a registered patient gets to book appointment with a doctor (who is also registered). So far I have done exactly what I want, but now I'm stuck.

On doctor's profile page, I have put a 'View Appointment' page (which shows the appointments that has book for that doctor). I even worked the notification where doctor gets to see that he/she has 'new appointments' (using count in mysql query).

Now, my problem, what if that doctor got more than one appointment? And I want to present data using loop so he/she can see all at once in a single page.

I need some guidance..

Here is the backend..

```
<?php
require_once '../inc/connect.php'; //my database connection, which also holds the functions file
if(!$doctor->is_loggedin())
{
$doctor->redirect('index.php');
}
// Getting the doctor id
$dct_id = $_SESSION['dct_session'];

//If need, further actions can be done using this query
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM dct WHERE dct_id=:dct_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":dct_id"=>$dct_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//this part is for viewing the appointments
$aptid=$_GET['apt_id'];
$stmt2=$DB_con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(dct_id) as aptid FROM apt WHERE dct_id=:aptid");
$stmt2->execute(array(":aptid"=>$aptid));
$aptRow=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$newApt=$aptRow['aptid'];

if($newApt>0)
{ ?>

<div class="alert alert-info">You have <?php print ($newApt) ?> New Appointment! <br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vwApt">View Appointment</button>
</div>

<?php }
else{ ?>

<div class="alert alert-warning">You have <?php print($newApt); ?> appointments!!</div>

<?php
}

?>
```

Notice the 'modal', I want appointment details appear in the modal-box.
I am fairly a beginner and using internet and some tutorials, got that much working, but I really need guidance.

Database has 'appointment' table with foreign keys for 'doctor id' and 'patient id, so in case I need to fetch data from multiple tables, I can do that. The appointment table has Patient's Name, Patient's details, Appointment time/day, and confirm / reject field.

I hope that I'm detailed in explaining the issue.

/* EDITED */

That's the code I finally used to get what I need. I created function and used in my view.

```
<?php
$apts=$this->db->prepare($query);
$apts -> execute();

if($apts->rowCount() > 0)
{
while($row=$apts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<div class="modal-body">
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['ptnt_fname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['ptnt_ds']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['apt_day']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['apt_time']; ?></td>
<td><button type="button" name="confirm" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"></button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

And that's the part I used to call this query

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM apt WHERE dct_id='$aptid'";
$doctor->viewApt($query);
?>
```

Thank you all for your kind response and guidance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will use this table as an example, we will fetch items that belong to vendor 1.

```
$sth = $conn -> prepare("select * from items where vendor_id = 1");
$sth -> execute();
$results = $sth -> fetchAll();
```

will produce this

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | name    | date                | vendor_id |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | apples  | 2015-08-19 11:27:27 |         1 |
|  2 | ornages | 2015-08-19 11:27:36 |         1 |
|  4 | bananas | 2015-08-19 11:27:41 |         1 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

to get how many items per the selected vendor

```
echo count($results); // 3
```

now let us loop through the results and display the name of items.

```
$html = '<ul>';
foreach ($result as $key => $result) {
    $html .= '<li>'.$result['name'] .'</li>' ;
}
$html .='</ul>';
```

output should be like this

```
. apples
. ornages
. bananas
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I've got to try it :)

Comment: I may be doing it wrong, because it's not working for me.
I guess..
    echo $apt->time;
time here represents column in the table, right??

Comment: I have got it working by writing this code in my 'view area'
    <?php
    $stmt2=$DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM apt WHERE dct_id='$newApt'");
    $stmt2->execute();
    if($stmt2->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    while($row=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    echo $row['ptnt_fname'];
    }
    }
    ?>

I'll try to work it out as exactly I want, but if I fail, I'll definitely be asking you again.

And if you got more elegant solution please let me know.
Also, if you can elaborate more on your given solution, I'll be grateful.

Comment: The code I wrote, gets the patient name from the table,  not exactly displaying separate. You see, if 2 patients have the appointment with same doctor, both patient's name displaying in a single column.

Else, selecting (all *) from the table to display new appointments, shows only 1 now.

And I'm getting lost as to how I sort this..

Comment: @Rafique, I updated the code with a table example and code.

Comment: it didn't work for me. Kept getting this error 'Trying to get property of non-object' but after spending time I found a solution which I have edited in my question.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$stmt2->execute();
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt2->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
echo $v;
}
```

put your code in a try block. and google it befor coming here
[W3c select data](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) scroll down to the bottom the PDO code is there